# Is there a way to embed curves into smaller vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, python, embeddings

I know about embeddings for words, but I would like to know if it is possible to do something similar for curves. What I mean by curves is a curve of a function. Say I have 1000 points corresponding to a curve for 0% to 100% every 0.1 and I would like to use this in a ML model but I don't want to use those 1000 points, but rather embedded them into a smaller vector so that two curves that are 'close' will have a vector closer.

I don't know if I explained myself clearly, so tell me if it is not the case !

Note : I would like to do this in Python

Comment: If you have a mathematical expression for the curves, you may also consider an approximation approach that can profit from that knowledge (e.g. [Tailor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) or [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)) together with a custom distance function in coefficient space, instead of a black-box approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike word embedding, where you can get "for free" the embeddings of words, in your use case you'll need to derive the embeddings yourself.

I would try an approach based on autoencoders. An autoencoder is a neural network architecture based on an encoder and a decoder. The idea is that the encoder takes the input data (in your case a curve) and encodes it to a small vector (in your case a vector with dimensionality < 1000). Then, the decoder takes this small vector and tries to reproduce the original input (in your case the original curve). Once the network is trained you'll have a way of extracting embeddings from your curves using the encoder layer.

[Here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) you have an example with images.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out !